# Selecting records that contain letters and/or non-alpha characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have table with  a string field ID with values looking like this:

```
 012345678
```

I want to select all the records from the ID field that begin with a 0 and have a letter in them, e.g `000A345B` or `0A32C450`. I also want to select records that begin with zero and contain a `-`, `/`  or a space.

*Note that records should begin with 0.*

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can catch any starting with 0 and having a letter in it using

```
WHERE ID LIKE '0%[A-Z]%'
```

You can catch any starting with 0 and having the characters 'A', '-', or '/' in them using

```
WHERE ID LIKE '0%[-A/]%'
```

You can also combine an explicit list and a range in one expression. You just need to remember that if the list includes a `-`, you need to specify it first, then list other characters and/or character ranges. To match all your requirements, for example, the predicate would look like this:

```
WHERE ID LIKE '0%[- /A-Z]%'
```